# Dropzone JS - Redirect after all files have uploaded

Tags: javascript, forms, dropzone

I have the below dropzone JS form which uploads files as It should.

```
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="dropzone" >
<div class="dz-message needsclick" style="margin-top:-20px">
<i data-feather="upload-cloud" style='margin-top:4px'></i>
<h4 style='font-weight:100'>Drag image here or click to upload</h4>
</div>
</form>
```

I am trying to get the page to redirect to another page when ALL uploads are completed. From a search, I found the below script, however it doesn't seem to do anything

```
<script>
dropzone.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
  window.location.href = ("Uploaded.php")
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED:**
use the following event '*queuecomplete*' instead of 'success'

Documentation:
https://www.dropzonejs.com/#events

At first, make sure your back-end is functioning properly (so the upload went OK). If so, success event should be fired once the file(s) have been uploaded.

Try with the below code in your script:

```js
// Need disabling autoDiscover, otherwise Dropzone will try to attach twice.
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
// or disable for specific dropzone:
// Dropzone.options.myDropzone = false;

$(function() {
  // initialize the dropzone
  var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dropzone");

  // change the location according to your preference
  // use queuecomplete instead of success event
  myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function(file) {
    window.location.href="test.php"
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks, however it still does not redirect. Console shows `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Dropzone`?

Comment: It has done it, This script needed to be after calling Dropzone.js :)

Comment: It actually redirects after uploading the first image, and not all the images?

Comment: Looks like I should be using `myDropzone.on("completemultiple", function(file) {` but it is not working??

Comment: try with:  
```myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function(file) {
    window.location.href="test.php"
  });```